# Comparison of two listbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new at VBA.So kindly help me on this matter.

My UserForm has two ListBox controls in it, each with two columns. For example, ListBox1

```
Name        Item

A            20

B            30
```

and listbox2:

```
Name        Item

A            20

B            40
```

When I click a CommandButton, the procedure below attempts to compare both ListBox controls and returns whether or not the data in each column of data is correct. I believe the best approach would be to first compare Column 1 of ListBox1 with Column 1 of ListBox2. If those are identical, then compare the second columns of both ListBox controls. The procedure is supposed to return a MsgBox that says "Correct" if all columns are identical. Otherwise, the program should return a mismatch error. Here is the code I've tried so far.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Dim p As Integer, Tabl() 
    Redim Tabl(0) 
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1 
        p = p + 1 
        Redim Preserve Tabl(p) 
        Tabl(p) = ListBox1.List(i) 
    Next i 
    For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1 
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(ListBox2.List(i), Tabl, 0)) Then 
           Msgbox"Correct" 
        End If 
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the program only calculates the first column repeatedly. How can I compare multiple columns?

Comment: Specifically which part of that are you having a problem with?

Comment: This doesn't sound like you're asking for help... This sounds like you're asking for people to do it for you. That's not what this site is for. If you show that you have put some effort into it yourself, and, i don't know, maybe ask a question, people would be more inclined to help.

Comment: This is not a question, it is just a statement of intent!

Comment: Sorry for late reply I got an accident on my knee..

 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Dim p As Integer, Tabl() 
    Redim Tabl(0) 
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1 
        p = p + 1 
        Redim Preserve Tabl(p) 
        Tabl(p) = ListBox1.List(i) 
    Next i 
    For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1 
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(ListBox2.List(i), Tabl, 0)) Then 
           Msgbox"Correct" 
        End If 
    Next i 
End Sub
It only calculate the first col repeatedly.so for better code I have asked. My intention not to order just to improve myself

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and a small evaluation of what your code does, you may be overthinking this. How about the following?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myMsg As String
    Dim byeMsg As String

    myMsg = "Same name chosen."
    byeMsg = "Those names don't match."

    If ListBox1.Value = ListBox2.Value Then
        MsgBox myMsg
    Else
        MsgBox byeMsg
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, instead of displaying a message using `MsgBox`, you could just as easily replace it with any code you need.